# Posting data to a form cURL

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying to post the data to a form using curl and save it in a file , here is the form in which I want to post the data , the webpage can be accessed here [form_webpage](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html)

```
<label for='Fldname'>Name</label></td><td>:</td><td><input type='text' name='name' id='Fldname'/>
    <label for='Fldemail'>Email</label></td><td>:</td><td><input type='text' name='email' id='Fldemail'/>
    <input type='password' name='x' id='Fldpwd'/>
    <input type='password' name='cpwd' id='Fldcpwd'/>
    <input type='radio' value='m' name='gender' id='Fldgendm'/> 
   <label for='Fldgendm'>Male</label> <input type='radio' value='f' name='gender' id='Fldgendf' />
   <label for='Fldgendf'>Female</label>
   <input type='checkbox' value='e' name='lang[]' id='Fldlange'/> Eng <input type='checkbox' value='t' name='lang[]'      id='Fldlangt'/> Tel <input type='checkbox' value='h' name='lang[]' id='Fldlangh' disabled />
    <select name='coun' multiple >
<option value=''>Choose Country</option>
<option value='91'>INDIA</option>
<option value='001'>USA</option>
<option value='002'>United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

I have done quite a bit of research and everytime i want to post to the form it is returning the same page 
I used

```
curl --data 'name=stirumer&email=123@gmail.com&x=test&cpwd=test&gender=m&lang[]=e&coun=91' "www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html" -o "3.html"

curl -Gd 'name=stirumer&email=123@gmail.com&x=test&cpwd=test&gen
der=m&lang[]=e&coun=91' "www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html" -o "3.html"

curl -X POST -F 'name=stirumer&email=123@gmail.com&x=test&cpwd=test&gender=m&lang[]=e&coun=91' www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html -o "2.html"

curl -F 'name=stirumer&email=123@gmail.com&x=test&cpwd=test&gend
er=m&lang[]=e&coun=91' www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html -o "1.html"

curl -X POST --data "name=stirumer&email=123@gmail.com&x=test&cpwd=test&gender=m&lang[]=e&coun=91" www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html
```

All of them return the same page..!!

Expected Output
[image: Should this be the output if it is correct?]

Need help guys!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to go about this, which I've found quite useful for similar activities.

In Firefox install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and [Firecurl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firecurl/). Start Firebug, and then browse to the page in question, and submit the form. Then in the Net Panel of Firebug, look at he Firecurl output. It gives you the CURL command line for the form submission, which you can cut and paste into a shell and execute. Good way to learn what all needs to be done for any POST.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to happen?  I went to your web page and tested it and I got, what I expected to happen.  When you manually go to that web page and fill in the information and click submit it just takes you back to the blank page.  If you were to do the same think with curl then you'll just get the blank page back as well.  I'd first make sure that your page works in a browser like you think it does.

When you use curl, it'll be like you filled in all of the form fields AND clicked submit.  It's not going to just put data into the form fields and then just return you that page.

Comment: Thanks that made some sense , what would be the right syntax out of all these to use curl!

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is fix your form that you are testing against.  Looking at your source, you might want to look over this page first http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: For example, if you were to set up your web service to process the form via GET, than you could simply fill in the form as you have it now, click "Register!" and then copy the url from the URL bar like such: `curl "http://www.cs.odu.edu/~stirumer/index.html?name=Test&email=test%40test.com&x=1234&cpwd=1234&gender=m&lang%5B%5D=e&coun=91&submit=Register+%21"`